# C++ is overloading the right way to do this

Tags: c++, c++17

In an attempt to improve my c++ I have decided to try to implement [msgpack](https://msgpack.org/). All sorts of data structures can be passed in order to be serialized.

Example data structure:

```
vector<tuple<char, vector<int>, int, string, double, map<int, vector<string> >, float > >
```

Is function overloading the correct way to call methods for the different data structures to be serialized or is there a template based method / paradigm to do so? Wright now I have a bunch of overloaded functions like shown below where I loop through stl data structures and call `pack` again for their primitive values.

`msgpack` has separate serialization headers for signed and unsigned integers of all sizes (8, 16, 32, 64) etc. All unsigned int's call `pack_uint` and all signed ints call `pack_int`.

Overloaded functions (how I'm doing it right now)

```
// container is a buffer to store the serialized data
template<typename T>
void pack(std::vector<T>& src, container& dest, bool initial = true);
template<typename ...T>
void pack(std::tuple<T...>& src, container& dest, bool initial = true);
template<typename T, typename S>
void pack(std::map<T, S>& src, container& dest, bool initial = true);
void pack(const char src, container& dest, bool initial = false);
void pack(const char* src, size_t len, container& dest, bool initial = false);
void pack(const std::string& src, container& dest, bool initial = false);
void pack_uint(const uint64_t& src, container& dest, bool initial = false);
void pack_int(const int64_t& src, container& dest, bool initial = false);
void pack(uint8_t& src, container& dest, bool initial = false);
void pack(uint16_t& src, container& dest, bool initial = false);
void pack(uint32_t& src, container& dest, bool initial = false);
void pack(uint64_t& src, container& dest, bool initial = false);
void pack(int8_t& src, container& dest, bool initial = false);
void pack(int16_t& src, container& dest, bool initial = false);
void pack(int32_t& src, container& dest, bool initial = false);
void pack(int64_t& src, container& dest, bool initial = false);
void pack(double& src, container& dest, bool initial = false);
void pack(float& src, container& dest, bool initial = false);
void pack(bool& src, container& dest, bool initial = false);
```

Entire repo [here](https://github.com/t348575/msgpack)

Comment: overload and template can go together, you do it btw for `std::vector<T>`, then depending of implementation, SFINAE might allows to factorize `std::integral_type`, or other "group"

Comment: Agreed with @Jarod42, I'd separate into buckets of types that can be handled similarly, e.g. maybe you handle all POD types the same way, maybe you handle all `std::vector<T>` the same way, etc.  I don't see utility in the way you've done it where e.g. `uint32_t` and `int32_t` have separate overloads, to me that screams for a template unless there's actual math you have to do that cares about integral size and signedness.

Comment: This looks like a better fit for CodeReview than here. But there's no glaring issue in this design. Notice that the standard library does basically the same thing for its "serialization": `operator<<`/`operator>>` for `std::ostream` and `std::istream`.